# Why does probability = 1 in my algorithm?

Tags: java

It returns `probability = 1`, where expTerm is 1102. I was expecting `probability = 0`.

```
public double getDeathProbability(NonEssentialNutrient neN) {
    CellParameters cP = new CellParameters();
    double expTerm = Math.pow((neN.getConc() / cP.getDeathConstant()), 2);
    System.out.println("ExpTerm is : " + expTerm);
    double probability = 1 - Math.exp((-expTerm));
    System.out.println("Death probability is : " + probability);
    return probability;
}
```

Comment: completely out of context. Anyway `Math.exp(-1102)` returns `0.0`. So which eventually turns your answer to `1.0`

Comment: If you use a calculator and type 1-e^-1102, you will see that 1 is exactly the result that should be returned?
This is no programming problem!

Comment: Probably on the border of being a question about programming, but as it has a clear question, I consider it valid.

Comment: Thank you, I miss type the formula.

Answer (score 0):

exp(-1102) is an incredibly small number that will numerically be approximated as 0. So 1 - 0 = 1.